# How to create dynamic form in django and implement add new record?

Tags: python, django

I want to make a page where user can input three form fields like 'car_name','bike_name','views'.

I want to make a html which initially have these 3 form input space. and further i want to add a button "add new entry". when user click on it then on same page 3 new form inputs will appear. and so on.

When user click submit button then all these fields have into database.

How can i do it?

I tried implementing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

but here we have to provide no of extra forms in views.py itself. but i want to set it from my html page.

how can i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Aison I can't show my code. if you getting problems in understanding the problem then let me know.

Comment: Which step you meet problem when you follow the doc.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/